# alternative to flexbox for image positioning?

Tags: html, css

I saw these [Flexbox alternative for IE9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24371408/flexbox-alternative-for-ie9) and [Alternative to display:flex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44705984/alternative-to-displayflex) and the answers says that I can replace it with `display: table;` or `display: table-cell;` but it didn't work for me.

so I asked before but I didn't get any luck, I'm trying to put two images with different heights side by side with the same height. I tried everything and I began playing with chrome Inspect and tried everything, I found that `display:flex` works great for me, but I want that person who still have the oldest IE can still use my website very good. I found modernizr but I didn't want to use any framework. so how can I do this?

this is the css and html:

```
<div class="container ok">
   <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/rock600x400.jpg"/>
   <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/paris.jpg"/>
</div>

.ok{
    display:flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
img {
    padding:5px;
    width: 49%;
    object-fit:cover;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.container {
  background-color: white;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 20px;
  overflow: auto;
  text-align: center;
}
```

**THANKS A LOT**

Comment: Did you try CSS-GRID?

Comment: I gave up and used flex

Comment: If you are having difficulty with CSS-Grid, here is a website to learn more about it: https://learncssgrid.com/

Comment: thanks a lot @Soban I will